# mysql server loses connection while fetching huge data set using pd.read_sql()

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

While fetching around 890 000 rows from MySQL database each with 60-65 columns using `pd.read_sql()`  the connection(created by SQLAlchemy engine) is dropped before the query is formed. Is there any other way to optimize fetching for this amount of data because I do need all the rows and columns and I would like to get rid of the Exception.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_outputs(engine):
   data = dict()

   with engine.connect() as conn: 
       data['tbl_1']= pd.read_sql('tbl_1',con=conn).to_json()
       data['tbl_2']= pd.read_sql('tbl_2',con=conn).to_json()
       data['tbl_3']= pd.read_sql('tbl_3',con=conn).to_json()
       engine.dispose()
   
   return {'data':data}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the default timeout using: "SET GLOBAL connect_timeout" property

```
conn.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout="<desired time>")
```

You can also set the timeout when creating the engine as:

```
create_engine(db_url, connect_args={'connect_timeout': <desired time>})
```